# "Все(,) как есть"

Tags: пунктуация

"Объяснили бы ему все(,) как есть" — я запятую не поставил. Но, может, она все-таки нужна?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваше предложение лучше употребить с глаголом "рассказать".
"***Рассказать всё как есть***" - устойчивое выражение, которое, вероятно, образовалось в результате усечения выражения "***всё так, как оно есть на самом деле***" и в сокращённом виде стало более удобным для частого употребления. В устойчивых выражениях такого типа запятая не ставится. Выражение "рассказать всё как есть" среди других многочисленных примеров Вы найдёте в "Справочнике по правописанию и литературной правке" Розенталя, в статье "Цельные по смыслу выражения",параграф 114.

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю, это предложение можно понять двояко.
Ежели слово "есть" можно заменить на "кушать", то запятая действительно нужна. В этом случае "как" является союзом и служит для связи придаточной части с главной.

---

Во втором случае, скорее всего, запятая не нужна, так как это выражение можно трактовать как неразложимое сочетание. Вторую часть предложения нельзя опустить без потери смысла.

**Корректно без запятой.**