# Верны ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

«Всё как есть о том, как все-таки есть». Вот предложение. Верны ли запятые?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: ["Все(,) как есть"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/%d0%92%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: @shampar Нет, здесь ситуация сложнее.

Comment: Игра слов есть, но «есть о том»... невозможно.

Comment: Второе "есть" в значении "питаться" или "быть"?

Comment: второе - «питаться», да...