# Пунктуация "все(,) что есть"

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология

Скажите, пожалуйста, считается ли фразеологизмом сочетание "все что есть"? Нужна ли запятая, например, в предложении "Постараюсь найти все, что есть"?
Существует вообще ПОЛНЫЙ список фразеологизмов? А то во многих правилах "...не обособляются устойчивые словосочетания: ...и т. д." Где искать это "и т. д."?
Спасибо

Comment: Фразеологи́зм — фразеологическая единица, идиома, устойчивое сочетание слов, которое характеризуется постоянным лексическим составом, грамматическим строением и известным носителям данного языка значением (в большинстве случаев – переносно-образным), **не выводимым из значения составляющих Ф. компонентов**. Это значение воспроизводится в речи в соответствии с исторически сложившимися нормами употребления.

(Источник: https://gufo.me/dict/bse/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC?ysclid=lfvhdlndq3713451558)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: ["Все(,) как есть"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/%d0%92%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: "Всё что есть" и "всё как есть" - абсолютно одинаковые ситуации.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы не поставил в вашем примере запятую, взяв за основу другой пример:

> Постараюсь найти все что угодно...

Приведенное выше сочетание является неразложимым, о чем говорит [статья](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_117) на этом сайте.

Что касается вашего примера, тут  все не так ясно, поскольку о нем в источниках не говорится. Однако не могу не сказать о том, что, поскольку оборот "все(,)что есть" стоит в конце предложения, корректнее его рассматривать в данном случае как устойчивое сочетание, потому что, на мой взгляд, в вашем примере реализуется значение "абсолютно все".

---

Об этом свидетельствует энное количество примеров из НКРЯ:

> Весь хлеб заберем! Давай все что есть! Она, матушка, думала, отстоит… [митрополит Тихон (Шевкунов). Несвятые святые (2011)]
>
> Жена начинает всхлипывать, видно, что даже ложь о проданной квартире вызывает в ней сильные эмоции. ― Это все что есть? ― говорит гадалка. ― Все что есть, ― говорит мужчина. [В. В. Лорченков. Бездна (2012) // «Волга», 2013]

Если вам интересна тема неразложимых сочетаний, то советую почитать [Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146).

Answer (score -1):

Да, нужна. Разные источники ставят её в разных местах, но с точки зрения пунктуации - после *"всё"*.

Comment: 1) Почему после всё? 2) Такой вопрос уже задавался, и на него уже есть ответ - то есть зачем отвечать?